# golang sync/atomic package?

Tags: go, atomic

I write a piece of code to record the num of request.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "sync/atomic"
)

var count int32 = 0

func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    count = atomic.LoadInt32(&count)
    atomic.AddInt32(&count, 1)
    log.Println("count:", count)
}
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU() - 1)
    http.HandleFunc("/", test)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I have considered the condition of concurrency, so I use the atomic pacakge.
I test the code via the apache ab tool

```
ab -c 400 -n 1000 http://localhost:8080/
```

the result is correct:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsQ4W.png)
However, someone said he got the 1004 or other number on his computer, I have tested many times of the code, but the result is correct on my computer, is there wrong with my way? 
I am new to go, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the package incorrectly; you should not be directly assigning/accessing the `count` variable, like you are with `count = ...`.

Comment: Please show the actual code you're using. This example isn't a valid use of atomic, because the log line accesses the `count` value directly, and you assign the result back to `count`

Comment: Always use the race detector, and `vet`. (also, `ab` is a poor tool to test your server, it's only http/1.0 and ins't even using keepalive here.)

Comment: try to build your server with -race flag like `go build -race` or running with `go run -race main.go`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `sync/atomic` package incorrectly. If you have an atomic variable, **ALL** reading and writing must be done using the atomic functions.

Here is your code fixed so that the `count` variable is not written to or read from non-atomically:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "sync/atomic"
)

var count int32

func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    currentCount := atomic.LoadInt32(&count)
    atomic.AddInt32(&count, 1)
    log.Println("count:", currentCount)
}
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU() - 1)
    http.HandleFunc("/", test)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```